# Reverse Y axis in Kendo-UI

Tags: javascript, html, kendo-ui

I am trying to make the direction of the values for the Y axis to go from 1 to 8000, 8000 at the top and 1 at the bottom.

```
 function createChart() {
                    $("#chart").kendoChart({
                        title: {
                            text: "Units sold"
                        },
                        dataSource: {
                            data: stats
                        },
                        categoryAxis: {                            
                            labels: {                                
                                step: 10,
                                format: "n2"
                            },
                        },
                        series: [{
                            type: "line",
                            field: "y",
                            categoryField: "x",
                            style: "smooth",
                            markers: {
                             visible: false
                          }
                        }],

                    });
                }

                $(document).ready(createChart);
```

Here is jfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nDS3S/31/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible and here is the solution: http://jsfiddle.net/nDS3S/32/

All you need is to add the following line of code:

```
valueAxis: {
   reverse: true,
}
```